# Smarty Template Engine fetch partitial content

Tags: php, smarty

How could i fetch only html output and save it while using smarty

For ex smarty fetch function works for below

```
Dear {$contact_info.name},

Welcome and thank you for signing up as a member of our user group.

Click on the link below to login with your user name
of '{$contact_info.username}' so you can post in our forums.

{$login_url}

List master

{include file="footer.tpl"}
```

But if i want to prefer only fetching included part of its included file part it is not properly working

Comment: I'm not sure what you are asking - do you want to capture the output into a variable? Or use only part of the template?

Comment: Yes i want to capture output but not the whole smarty output, only included file content

Answer (score 0):

You can use [fetch](http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/api.fetch.tpl) to get the output into a variable:

```
$output = $smarty->fetch('email.tpl');
```